# Focus Testing in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, focus

I am currently using opencv, image and pygame for capturing frames from a hd webcam. What I want to achieve is to check if the captured frames are focused or not. This is aka focus testing but I couldn't come up with a solution in Python. IMHO problem can be reduced to determining the blurness percentage of each pixel and come up with a decision. What is the name of this algorithm I am seeking for ? Does anyone have any experience implementing similar algorithms in Python ?

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You could apply a Gaussian filter to the image, take difference, the smaller the more blurry the image is, the greater the less it is ...

Comment: You can't rally determine how blurry a pixel is only an image or a segment of the image, check out http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Ndimage their pretty fast implementatios.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if an image is blurry this [Is there a way to detect if an image is blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry) might be able to  help you, pretty interesting.