# blurred image removal in an image database

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, fft, ifft

I have a dataset of about 2000 images. This database contains some blurred images.
How can I automatically remove the blurred images from this database?

I read about fourier transformation to remove the blurred images. First I need to transform my images into fourier domain and then by applying some threshold I will be able to identify the blurred images. Could anybody give me some sample code in matlab for this? I don't know how to determine the threshold. Are there any way to determining this threshold?

Comment: To determine the threshold, just take a few clear pictures, a few blurry ones, and look at their frequency distributions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if an image is blurry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry)

Answer (score 4):

This task is really not so simple, if you remove all the images that doesn't contain high frequencies you will end up removing many images that contain smooth scenes even though they are not blurred.

There is no 100% in computer vision, the best thing for you (in my opinion) is to make a human aided software, your software should suggest on the images that it thinks should be removed, but the final call must be made by a human being.