# How can I detect if a picture is blurry with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, motion-blur

I have a jpeg data url in a javascript string. Is there a way I can detect the "blurriness" of the picture? The pictures come from a video that is being processed in-browser.

I understand that it isn't simple, and there is no definitive standard of blurriness, yet is there a way to measure blurriness?

Comment: do you have an original to compare against?

Comment: Usually you would look for high frequency content in the autocorrelation (power spectrum). The lower the high frequency content, the blurrier the image.

Comment: you should use more powerful language for this (c++ lets say). this will help you start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry

Comment: @sgroves no, the images are end user generated with no guaranteed good versions.

Comment: @pregmatch Thanks, I'm aware of other tools available to do this already, I'm just wondering if this has been done in-browser yet. It would save alot of server side processing if the check if the images are ok in the browser

Answer (score 4):

There are several approaches to blur detection, I implemented a really simple one once and wrote this blog post about it: http://www.codeoclock.com/2015/06/05/blur-detection-javascript/

Code can be found here: https://github.com/timotgl/inspector-bokeh

The algorithm isn't very refined, but I was able to detect images with a lot of blur somewhat reliably.

Comment: A simple test with this blurry image https://www.facebook.com/postcardnow/photos/a.115486162502141.1073741828.110080529709371/130127087704715/    shows a Blur score of 0.36.  Your library may have to be improved!

Comment: @TimLong Yes it's experimental. Feel free to tune the algorithm and contribute on GitHub. I'm not actively maintaining the project.