# How calculate sharpness (Opencv)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Help me, please. I need to calculate sharpness of image in opencv, but I don't now how do it. I researching and not found anything for me.

Comment: You didn't search very hard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry

Answer (score 0):

Working at the local institute of computer vision back in 2010 there was a colleague writing a paper about sharpness in endoscopy, I remember.

The paper is german but I'll tell you their mentioned three ways to measure sharpness:
http://www.lfb.rwth-aachen.de/bibtexupload/pdf/GRO10a.pdf

1. Variance
2. Sum Modulus Difference (SMD)
3. Perceptual Sharpness Metric (PSM)

they found SMD to be the best sharpness criteria for THEIR specific imagedata.

Here's another link with SMD, Variance and some other sharpness functions:
http://guppy.mpe.nus.edu.sg/~mpeangh/publications/f0544.pdf