# Is there a way to check whether a image is gaussian blur on php?

Tags: php, gaussian

I have one million gaussian blur image ，but i'm not sure all the image is gaussian blur image,so is there a way to check whether a image is gaussian blur on php?

Non-Gaussian blur FIG.
[image: not a gaussian blur]
Gaussian blur FIG.
[image: gaussian blur]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107560/simple-way-to-check-if-an-image-bitmap-is-blur

Comment: Can you post one or two example images of what they look like ? there are different solutions to this but it all boils down to what kind of images we're looking at here

Comment: Run edge detection, see if you find zero edges?