# Detect if UIImage is blurry

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, image-processing, uiimage

Is there any way to detect if an image is blurry? My use case is that I require users to upload very clear images. Would be nice to force them to retake a blurry image.

Comment: I highly doubt that there is anything practical for this but let's wait and see...

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry?rq=1 It is in the realated questions for this one.