# Is here any way to find out whether an image is blurry or not using Laplacian operator

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I am working on this project where I have to automate the sharpness calculation of an camera taken image without actually looking a the image. I have tried many detection methods, but finally I am going further with Laplacian operator using openCV.

Now, the laplacian operator in the openCV returns the image matrix. But, I have to get boolean output whether the image is blurry or not depending upon my threshold.

Any link, algorithm or IEEE paper for the same would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Following might be helpful http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/

Comment: so you can/will capture multiple images and choose the setting where the sharpest image was captured?

Comment: Lets take Galaxy S6. Now, I have to check how much the focusing performance of S6 has degraded over a period of time. For that, I'll have to take several photos of same image but not manually through my eyes, rather using my program.

Comment: Look for "perceptual sharpness metric" (PSM) for example from yang et al 2006

Answer (score 3):

You will find a lot of infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry).

Also the paper cited in one of the answers if quite interesting: [Analysis of focus measure operators for shape from focus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UHr3GQEkQwYnlDY2dKNTdudjg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579247/6302996

```
Laplacian(gray, laplacianImage, CV_64F);
Scalar mean, stddev; // 0:1st channel, 1:2nd channel and 2:3rd channel
meanStdDev(laplacianImage, mean, stddev, Mat());
double variance = stddev.val[0] * stddev.val[0];

double threshold = 2900;

if (variance <= threshold) {
    // Blurry
} else {
    // Not blurry
}
```