# How to detect image with small depth

Tags: image-processing, javacv, opencv3.0

Currently, i am doing a project related to image processing. Before any thing is done. The blurry images should be dropped indeed. However, i found some of images are really interesting which are "shallow depth of field". I don't want my blur detection algorithm( variance of Laplacian ) dropping all these nice images at all. i have done a observation with a training set to get a new threshold. It can recognize part of the images i want. Are there any Algorithm can detect small depth images with higher accuracy.If any of you have an idea(it is better if related to opencv) please share to me. Thanks indeed.

Comment: I presume you mean *"shallow depth of field"*?

Comment: This is quite relevant... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry

Comment: Blurry detection is done in the previous week. Now my goal is to find out all image with small depth of field.