# OpenCV blur detection with Laplace crash with low resolution images

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on a blur detection with OpenCV for Android and used following code found here on Stackoverflow which seemed to work correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245961/1804084

Now, my problem is that it crashs, if the resolution of the image is too small. In the sample code the transformed image gets resized to 2000*2000, but only if it is bigger than that.

It happens here:

```
Imgproc.Laplacian(matImageGrey, laplacianImage, CvType.CV_8U);
```

I have tested it serveral times and no crash with big images!

No crash image resolution: 1048 * 1048

Crash with resolution: 511*511

Does anybody now why this happens? It seems that there is a minimum image resolution size needed, but I can not find any info in the OpenCV documentation or in the internet.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the crash log to your question so people know what the error is

Comment: No crash log! Native library C++ crash. Do not know how to detect that with Android Studio.