# Detect if image is blurry in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I am trying to find a good solution to detect if a UIImage is blurry. I have looked around quite a bit and most solutions are not swift ready or not too iOS friendly. I am trying to find a solution I can easily adopt in one of my iOS projects to detect if an image coming from the camera is blurry.

Any solution out there?

Comment: I cant give you a programmatic solution. But have you tried to compare neighboring pixels in a certain radius? 
An image is blurry if pixel share a very similar rgb value to the next and to the next and so on. 
Theoretically, wouldnt you just need to compare the pixels and check if they fall in a certain threshold?

Comment: I saw some discussions on that approach. Probably I didn't understand how to actually accomplish that in Swift.

Comment: There are plenty of good solutions.  Just none that I know of that do the legwork for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766036/793607

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if an image is blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry)