# Screenshot for the video - FTP Video Upload

Tags: php, video, ftp

I am uploading the video using FTP, what exactly I am doing that is clicking screenshot from video for the first frame,
but what exactlty it is happening is screenshot is getting blurred, obviously if the first frame would be blur, eventually the screenshot will be blur only.

Can I do any other way to click a steady picture?
Here is my FTP Code where I am clicking screenshot(thumbnail).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && $_FILES["file"]["name"] != ''){
    $newfilename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/home/projectname/public_html/master/assets/user_videos/".$newfilename);
    if($upload){
        $thumbnail_name =  preg_replace('"\.(mp4|avi|flv|vob|oggg)$"', '.jpg', $newfilename);
        $movie = "/home/projectname/public_html/master/assets/user_videos/".$newfilename;
        $thumbnail = "/home/projectname/public_html/master/assets/user_videos/".$thumbnail_name;
        $command = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i '.$movie.' -f image2 -vframes 1 '.$thumbnail.' 2>&1';
        $output = passthru($command);
        $data = array('status' => 1 , 'video'=> $newfilename, 'screenshot'=> $thumbnail_name, 'message' => 'Video successfully uploaded' );
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here? If ffmpeg can recognize if a frame is blurry or not before taking a screenshot?

Comment: Not an example in PHP, but could lead you to a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198278/538016

Comment: @MagnusEriksson didn't understand u what you are trying to tell?