# How do I compute Laplacian in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I am currently trying to design a Node.js code that would be able to tell if an image is blurry or not. In order to achieve that, I took my inspiration [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry). So what I need to do is compute a matrix laplacian (is that how we say ?) and then compute variance.

I have no problem doing it with OpenCV (using [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs)) :

```
# load image
_cvImg = cv.imread _file

# get grayscale image
_cvImgGray =_cvImg.bgrToGray()

# Compute laplacian
_laplacian = _cvImgGray.laplacian(cv.CV_8U)

# Get the standard deviation
_meanStdDev = _laplacian.meanStdDev()

_stddevarray = _meanStdDev.stddev.getDataAsArray()
_stdDeviation = _stddevarray[0]

# Get the variation
_variation = Math.pow(_stdDeviation, 2)
```

But now, I am using Tensorflow.js and it is really less easy... Here what I tried to do:

```
# load image
_cvImg = cv.imread _file

#convert frame to a tensor
try
    _data = new Uint8Array(_frame.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB).getData().buffer)
    _tensorFrame = tfjs.tensor3d(_data, [_frame.rows, _frame.cols, 3])
catch _err
    @log.error "Error instantiating tensor !!!"
    @log.error _err.message

# get grayscale image
_grayscaleFrame = _tensorFrame.mean(2).expandDims(2)

# prepare convolution to get laplacian
laplaceFilter = tfjs.tensor2d([[0,1,0], [1,-4,1], [0,1,0]])
laplaceFilter3D = laplaceFilter.expandDims(2)

# get laplacian
_laplacian = tfjs.conv1d _tensorFrame, laplaceFilter3D, 1, 'same'

# get standard deviation
_standardDeviation = tfjs.moments(_laplacian2).variance.buffer().values[0]

# get variance
_variance = _standardDeviation * _standardDeviation

# dispose tensor to avoid memeory leaks
_tensorFrame.dispose()
```

Not so surprisingly, the above code doesn't work. I know that my convolution should be two dimensional (tf.conv2d) instead of 1-D (tf.conv1d) since I am working on an image. If I look at [tf.conv2d in API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#conv2d), I can see this signature:

```
tf.conv2d (x, filter, strides, pad, dataFormat?, dilations?, dimRoundingMode?)
```

And filter should be a tf.Tensor4D ! But I have no idea how the following filter matrix could be converted to tf.Tensor4D

```
    1
1   4   1   
    1
```

Am I doing something wrong ? How can I get laplacian of a matrix in Tensorflow.js ? i.e How can I perform a simple convolution between my tensor2d representing my image and the above filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convolution can be performed over the 2d tensor by first expanding its dimension. Likewise for the filter by using `tf.reshape`

After the computation, tf.squeeze will remove dimensions of shape 1, thus returning a 2d tensor

```js
const x = tf.tensor2d(Array.from({length: 16}, (_, k) => k+1), [4, 4]); // input image 2d

const filter = tf.tensor2d([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [3, 3]) // input filter 2d

x.reshape([1, ...x.shape, 1]).conv2d(filter.reshape([...filter.shape, 1, 1]), 1, 'valid').squeeze().print() // conv
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
// Reads the image, converts to gray and makes shape (1, width, height, 1) [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
let _grayscaleFrame = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas).mean(2).toFloat().expandDims(0).expandDims(-1); 
                                                          

// prepare convolution to get laplacian
let laplaceFilter = tf.tensor2d([
          [0, 1, 0],
          [1, -4, 1],
          [0, 1, 0]
]).expandDims(-1).expandDims(-1); // [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

// get laplacian
let _laplacian = _grayscaleFrame.conv2d(laplaceFilter, 1, 'valid').squeeze()
```