# Is openCV only for C developers?...any openCV for VB developers?

Tags: vb.net, opencv, focus, blur

I am looking for a function callable within VB.net that would measure how out of focus or blurry a still video frame is.

Comment: There are probably lots of ways! What have you tried? Been a while since I've done VB, but you can probably connect via a DLL, have a C process do openCV and connect via a socket in VB, spin up a CORBA ORB that contains C code that interfaces with openCV and the VB client...

Answer (score 4):

Emgu CV works with .Net languages (naturally including VB.Net).
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

There have been a great discussion on Stack Overflow already as well,
[.Net (dotNet) wrappers for OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv)

And some links(with accepted answers) from stackoverflow regarding how much blurry a frame is
[Is there a way to detect if an image is blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry)
[Detection of Blur in Images/Video sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180327/detection-of-blur-in-images-video-sequences?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenCV homepage](http://opencv.org/):

`It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android.`

So the answer is no, it is not just for C developers, but no, not VB developers.

Ask [here](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/) for more detailed information.

Since it's an API however, it can be wrapped so that you can call it's functions from a programming language of your choice.

Thankfully this has been done for you already! [It's called Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).